# Unable to setup Jasmine for my Javascript project

Tags: jasmine

I have created a JavaScript project and need to use Jasmine for unit testing. I have followed following steps : 
1. **npm install jasmine --save-dev** -  from project root directory
2. Now when I try to initilize it using  
           **jasmine init**
It is giving me the below error. 
**'jasmine' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Any lead to solve the issues will be appreciated.

Comment: You either have to call Jasmine though the `node_modules/.bin/jasmine` path or install Jasmine globally. See [the guide on the npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine#installation).

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem (using Windows). Just do this:

```
npm install -g jasmine
```

It is now recognizable.

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed it locally in your project you can use the following from the root path of project.

```
npx jasmine init
```

Reference- https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html

Need not install globally.

Comment: Is this the reason for the error? I had been working without such an error but suddenly bumped into this error when trying to run jasmine on one of the repos. Already had `jasmine.json` file , so deleted it and tried `npx jasmine init`. The same error persists.

Comment: npx doesn't install jasmine in way that's acciable by the command line. So this really doesn't solve the stated problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per project installs are not by default on the $PATH used by the command line. They need to be run via a npm script. Put this in your `package.json`.

> test": "jasmine"

Then run `npm test` or `npm run test`. You can also run `npx jasmine` for on off usage but that won't create a local install. `npm -g install jasmine` will install jasmine globally allowing for direct local use via the command line but is machine specific.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine#installation